# Select every other row as male/female from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, modulo

I've got a table containing persons gender-coded as 0 and 1. I need to select every other row as male/female. I thought I could manage this somehow by using modulo and the gender-codes 0 and 1, but I haven't managed to figure it out yet...

The result I'm looking for would look like this:

```
+-----+--------+-------+
| row | gender | name  |
+-----+--------+-------+
|   1 | female | Lisa  |
|   2 | male   | Greg  |
|   3 | female | Mary  |
|   4 | male   | John  |
|   5 | female | Jenny |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

etc.

The alternative is to do it in PHP by merging 2 separate arrays, but I would really like it as a SQL query...

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure I get your question, are you trying to retrieve just the males (or females) from your database? It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please clarify your requested result..

Comment: i need to retrieve every other row as male/female: e.g. 1. Lisa, 2. Greg, 3. Mary, 4. John, 5. Jenny

Comment: Your logic appears flawed as there is no guarantee that there will be equal numbers of men and women. How do you propose that should be dealt with?

Comment: Does your table include a sequential ID?

Comment: If that's your required result, what does the table look like that you're selecting from?

Comment: @DavidThomas the table i'm selecting from looks the same except the persons are not in any particular order...

Comment: @MarkBannister my table does include a sequential id (the primary key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Mikael's solution but without the need to order the resultset multiple times -

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT people.*,
        IF(gender=0, @mr:=@mr+1, @fr:=@fr+1) AS rank
    FROM people, (SELECT @mr:=0, @fr:=0) initvars
) tmp
ORDER BY rank ASC, gender ASC;
```

To avoid having to order both the inner and outer selects I have used separate counters (@mr - male rank, @fr - female rank) in the inner select.

Answer (score 2):

Do two subqueries to select male and female. Use ranking function to have them enumerated.

```
Males:
1 | Peter
2 | John
3 | Chris

Females:
1 | Marry
2 | Christina
3 | Kate
```

Then multiplay ranking result by x10 and add 5 for females. So you have this:

```
Males:
10 | Peter
20 | John
30 | Chris

Females:
15 | Marry
25 | Christina
35 | Kate
```

Then do the UNION ALL and sort by new sort order/new ID.

Together it should like this (pseudo code)

```
SELECT
Name
FROM
(subquery for Males: RANK() AS sortOrd, Name)
UNION ALL
(subquery for Females: RANK()+1 AS SortOrd, Name)
ORDER BY SortOrd
```

Result should be like this:

```
Males and Females:
10 | Peter
15 | Marry
20 | John
25 | Christina
30 | Chris
35 | Kate
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn' noticed it's MySQL related question. Not sure if MySQL has got ranking functions.

Comment: It doesn't but you can achieve the same using user variables.

Answer (score 2):

Found [Emulate Row_Number()](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1440#1098) and modified a bit for your case.

```
set @rownum := 0;
set @pg := -1;

select p.name, 
       p.gender
from
  (
    select name,
           gender,
           @rownum := if(@pg = gender, @rownum+1, 1) as rn, 
           @pg := gender as pg 
    from persons
    order by gender
  ) as p
order by p.rn, p.gender
```

Try on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05b02/8)

Note: From [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable
>   and read the value within the same statement. You might get the
>   results you expect, but this is not guaranteed.

I will leave it up to you do decide if you can use this. I don't use MySQL so I can't really tell you if you should be concerned or not.

Comment: we're getting closer, but not quite there yet. you're code only works partially, as the rows seem to give genders in equal number, but not strictly as every other row. This only becomes apparent with more rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05b02/1

Comment: @darwin Looks like a `order by gender` in the derived table took care of that.

Answer (score 0):

> I've got a table containing persons gender-coded as 0 and 1

Then why would you make assumptions on the order of rows in the result set? Seems to me transforming the 0/1 into 'male'/'female' is far more robust:

```
select name, case gender when 0 then 'male' else 'female' end
from Person
```

Comment: the reason for why i used 0 and 1 was beause I thought I could achieve what I wanted using modulo 2

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT alias.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GENDER ORDER BY GENDER) rnk
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY rnk, GENDER DESC
```